# What is the radiation field of a black body with temperature $T$ translating at speed $v$?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, thermal-radiation, radiometry

Suppose I have a spherical black body at temperature $T$ with radius $R$. When stationary in a vacuum at zero Kelvin, it produces an incoherent radiation field according to [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law)
$$
B_\nu = \frac{2 h\nu^3}{c^2} \frac{1}{e^{-h\nu/kT}-1}
$$
producing a spectral flux given by
$$
F_\nu = \frac{2 h\nu^3}{c^2} \frac{2\pi}{e^{-h\nu/kT}-1} \frac{R^2}{r^2}.
$$
The factor of $2\pi$ is the number of Steradians each element of the sphere's surface radiates into, and the final factor in the product is the ratio of the area of the sphere to the area of the imaginary sphere the radiation has been spread out on.

So far, so good. This is basic physics.

Now, if we change to a reference frame moving with velocity $-\vec{v}$, it sees the sphere moving at $\vec{v}$. What radiation pattern is seen in that moving frame, and why doesn't the radiation produce a net force on the sphere?

Having not bothered with the derivation, yet, I would expect the [Dopper shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) to definitely be relevant. Since the radiation is incoherent, though, does that make it so the [headlight effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_beaming) doesn't kick in?

The frame where the sphere is stationary certainly doesn't see it accelerating, so it cannot be accelerating in the moving frame, either. Both the headlight and Doppler effect would, naively, cause an imbalance of forces that would tend to decelerate the sphere. Since that is, obviously, not the case, what factor counter-balances the Doppler (and possible headlight) effect?

Comment: I suppose that the [Terrell–Penrose effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation) may also be relevant, since that says that the *apparent* shape of a spherical surface remains spherical.

Comment: Excellent question. I'm reminded of an imperfect complement: a mirror moving along a set of 1D rails within a cavity filled with radiation. The mirror suffers a drag force when it moves relative to the walls of the cavity, which arises from both the headlight and the Doppler effects. Plane waves reflecting off the mirror impart momentum according to the angle between the propagation vector and the surface normal (cosine of that angle squared). When the mirror moves, the headlight effect gives more plane waves going against the mirror in the mirror-stationary frame.

Comment: In my imperfect complement above, I don't see how incoherence negates the effect of the headlight effect (maybe I'm confused: the pressure from a single reflected wave is non-negative no matter the phase, so making more waves impinge from a given direction will necessarily give a net force in said direction). Next, the role of the Doppler effect is more subtle, IMO. It changes which frequencies of waves contribute the most to pressure on the mirror's two sides. Overall, if one integrated over all frequencies, one would find that the Doppler effect decreases(!) the drag force on the mirror.

Comment: One will have different effects depending on the spectral distribution of the radiation hitting the mirror. One finds that if the spectral distribution integrates to a finite total energy, there is necessarily a drag force. Of the non-integrable spectral distributions, the drag force vanishes for a spectral distribution going like the frequency cubed (makes sense: QED vacuum energy density).

Comment: I brought up this imperfect complement to try to emphasize the non-intuitive (to me)  behavior of the Doppler shift and the persistence of the headlight effect in a related problem. It could be the problem isn't so related, but it's where my perspective is based. Could you discuss your thoughts on incoherence a little more? I also feel that, in your radiation problem, you could make your "acceleration in the stationary frame" argument for any spectral distribution of radiation and for any shaped object - maybe making your question more general will find a simple answer.

Comment: Compare with the somewhat similar question. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/518385/how-does-observed-black-body-radiation-change-with-observer-speed I now think the relation is P $\propto P_{stationary} v/c$

Comment: @DavidJonsson Nowhere does this question ask about total power radiated.

Answer (score 0):

Longitudinal radiation is Doppler shifted with

$$\nu'  {\displaystyle ={\sqrt {\frac {1-\frac{v}{c} }{1+\frac{v}{c} }}}\,\nu}$$

If that relation is put into the first relation $$B_\nu = \frac{2 h\nu^3}{c^2} \frac{1}{e^{-h\nu/kT}-1}$$

it becomes $$B_\nu' = \frac{2 h \left(\frac {1-\frac{v}{c} }{1+\frac{v}{c} }\right)^\frac{3}{2} \nu^3}{c^2} \frac{1}{e^{-h \sqrt {\frac {1-\frac{v}{c} }{1+\frac{v}{c} }} \nu/kT}-1}$$

A series expansion with higher terms skipped might be more intelligible.

Integrate this function over the surrounding sphere to find the net radiation pressure. Treat the velocity as vectorial and only include the result from a radiation direction which is parallel to the velocity. The other radiation component perpendicular to the velocity should be calculated from the radiation transformed with transverse doppler shift.

Comment: Sorry, David, but this does not address the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

The radiation does produce a net force on the sphere. The sphere's velocity is constant, but its mass is decreasing, so its momentum is decreasing, and $F=dp/dt$.

The Doppler and headlight effects are both present and give the light emitted in the forward direction a larger (three-)momentum than the light emitted in the reverse direction. The reaction force on the sphere is in the backward direction and decreases its momentum without affecting its velocity.

Comment: Interesting, and strange to think of a force being exerted without a delta v. Do you have a link to a derivation that shows that the force actually matches $v \mathrm{d}m / \mathrm{d}t$?

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to [Doppler shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) the wavelengths before [deriving Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Derivation).

Comment: It doesn't seem demanding to derive this but I asked anyway here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/683971/what-would-plancks-law-become-if-derived-from-doppler-shifted-wavelengths