# How does observed black body radiation change with observer speed?

Tags: thermal-radiation, observers, speed

Black body radiated power is

$$P =\sigma T^{4} \tag{1}$$

and temperature in a gas is related to particle speed as

$$ T = \frac{mv_{{th}}^2}{3k_{B}}  \tag{2}$$

where $v_{th}$ is the root mean square of the particles speed, leading to

$$ P =\sigma T^{4} 
= \sigma \left(\frac{mv_{{th}}^2}{3k_{B}}\right)^{4} 
= \sigma \frac{m^4v_{{th}}^8}{27 k_{B}^4} 
=  {\propto v_{th}^8} \tag{3}$$

Does this mean that if we want to determine the speed dependency of the radiated power, like if we move relative the particle distribution with speed v, it transforms as

$$ P \propto (v_{th}^2- v^2)^4 \tag{4}$$

where T has transformed as

$$ T \propto v_{th}^2 - v^2 \tag{5} $$

?

If we know the distribution of the particles speeds $v_i$ by for example Doppler shift of spectral lines, do we then determine radiated power adjusted for a relative speed like

$$ P \propto \sum_i (v_i^2 - v^2)^4 \tag{6}$$

?

If we measure both spectral line Doppler shifts, and radiated power, can we then determine our relative speed v to this particle distribution by the same relation $P \propto (v_{th} -v)^8$?

This does not look like how astrophysicists work, but I can't find anything wrong with this reasoning either. The solution seems to be that particle speed in this sense should be determined relative to closer particles.

We apparently do not think that we experience a power increase when moving relative to black body radiation ${\propto (v_{th}+v)^8}$. Most scriptures mention Doppler shift to be the only effect which means that experienced increase in radiated power is ${\propto \frac{v}{c}}$. How can this situation be clarified?

Comment: Where did you find the expression for $T$ in terms of $v_{th}$?

Comment: @SRS The expression is taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_velocity

Comment: Your fourth equation contains two errors. $v$ is the root mean square of the instantaneous velocities of the particles making up what must be a gas, in the rest frame of that gas. This does not transform linearly with observer velocity and its transformed value $v^2 + v^2_{obs}$ is no longer related to temperature in the same way.

Comment: Thanks @my2cts! I will try to change once I have figured out to what. From what I see from what you write T should change to T $\propto (v_{th}^2 - v_{obs}^2)$ and P $\propto (v_{th}^2 -v_{obs}^2)^4 $, right? And only one third (in some sense) of the gas transforms this way.

Comment: Consider an observer moving with a velocity v through a radiation bath of temperature $T_0$. The observer will see an **anisotropy** in the radiation
field with the effective temperature in a direction making an angle θ with the direction of motion being $T(\theta) = T_0 [\gamma(1 + v \cos \theta)]^{−1}$

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of molecular velocities changes if you move toward a star from your vantage. But the apparent rms speed would increase the same whether you moved toward or away. Clearly that couldn’t distinguish red or blue shifts due to bulk motion which do depend on direction.
The problem is Stefan’s law comes from Plank statistics which you’d have to try to adapt from the beginning.

It seems you are trying to say a moving object is effectively hotter because the rms molecular speed would be more. Normally we jump inside or move with the object , calculate thermal radiation, then transform that radiation to our original frame. You are trying a direct route. Interesting but that could be very tricky! Worth thinking about however. It might have already been studied, most things have. It would still have to give the usual red shit blue shift answers of course.

Answer (score 0):

When you move through black body radiation --- as we move through the Cosmic Miicrowave Background Radiation (CMBR) --- the Dopler effect makes the radiation appear to have a higher temperature ahead of us, and look to be at lower temperature behind us. By measuring the temperature difference we can determine our velocity with respect to the rest frame of the CMBR. I don't understand  why you want to introduce the relation between temperature and RMS gas velocities.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this is not what I am asking for. A lot of stars and pieces of galaxies are being measured. Such objects are what I am primarily interested in.