# What would Planck's law become if derived from Doppler shifted wavelengths?

Tags: special-relativity, thermal-radiation, wavelength, doppler-effect

[Derivation of Plancks law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Derivation) does not involve Doppler effects on wavelength. What would Planck's law become if derived from Doppler shifted wavelengths?

Answer (score 1):

All the frequencies are Doppler shifted by the same factor, including the frequency at which the spectrum peaks. The characteristic temperature of the function only appears in the dimensionless ratio $h\nu/kT$, so the transformed Planck function looks like a Planck function with a temperature Doppler shifted by the same factor as the frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

The Lorentz boost of a Planck spectrum is just a Planck spectrum of a new temperature. If you Doppler shift by redshift $Z$ all the photons of energies $E_{Old}$ in a Planck distribution of temperature $T_{Old}$, the new photon energies $E_{New}=\frac{E_{Old}}{1+Z}$ form a new Planck distribution of temperature $T_{New}=\frac{T_{Old}}{1+Z}$.

Comment: Can you show this with a derivation based on the Lorentz boosted wavelengths?

Comment: This answer is not according to the question. The Doppler effect should be considered before determining the "Planck distribution".